# @try@catch block not catching inside exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, objective-c-runtime

OK, I've never seen this before. Here is my code:

```
    @try {
        [self.avPlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
        [self.avPlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate"];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {

    } @finally {

    }
```

You can quite clearly see, I have those 2 lines of code in the @try block. However, it's still crashing my app. Here's the uncaught exception message:

> Cannot remove an observer <SoulHLECellView 0x7fa8d2b536b0> for the key path "status" from <AVPlayer 0x7fa8d714ad70> because it is not registered as an observer.

So, very clearly, this is being caused by the code I've posted above. How the heck is this possible? What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you using `try/catch` for this? Write your code so you only attempt to remove the observer if you have added the observer.

Comment: @rmaddy truthfully because it's not my code and it's dense and I don't want to break anything or cause new bugs.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error *on OS X*, all my attempts succeed in catching the exception. Look at the stack trace, that maybe will contain a clue. There is nothing wrong *per se* with your code (any philosophical issues aside ;-))

Comment: There is nothing about that log line that indicates an exception was thrown.  It could just be the system telling you that something bad happened without actually tossing an exception in the process of doing so.

Comment: @bbum - On *OS X* it is definitely throwing an exception, and the message agrees with what the OP posted. Of course the OP is on iOS and I did not test that, so it is possible iOS is different.

Comment: @CRD Sure is.  I just looked at the source.   Huh.

Comment: I have (finally) tested your code on iOS (simulator only), as with OS X the code an exception is thrown and the code catches it. So your problem is not reproducible and there must be something else in your app which is causing things to go awry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question as to *why* you aren't actually catching the exception, there are certain types of exceptions that cannot be caught; see http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html for a pretty good explanation of what these are, what their causes are, and what to do about them.  I suspect that the exception that's actually getting thrown is a runtime exception that you can't actually handle with `@try/@catch`.

To triage, you can try setting a breakpoint on `-[NSException raise]` in `CoreFoundation` or `objc_exception_throw` in `libobjc.A.dylib`, and more than likely that breakpoint will capture what the actual exception is and give you a clue as to why you aren't catching it.

All that being said, [@gnasher729](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3255455/gnasher729) hit the nail on the head as to how best to handle this type of situation in the long run (i.e. code that you want to actually release out into the world).

Comment: Can someone who down-voted this answer please explain why?  The question was NOT "Should I use try/catch"; it was "how is it possible for try/catch to NOT CATCH this exception".

Answer (score 7):

In Objective-C, exceptions are thrown for programming errors. You DON'T catch exceptions. You fix the bugs in your code.

The bug in your code is quite obvious: You try to remove an observer that doesn't exist. Check whether you actually create the observer, or whether you have already removed it. Only call removeObserver if there is an observer.

Do NOT use TRY / CATCH for this. When there is an exception, let it crash your app, figure out what causes the exception, then FIX YOUR BUG.

Comment: Good answer, in general.  In this case, I don't think there is an exception being thrown at all.

Answer (score 1):

*A sort of "none answer", based on previous comments.*

Let's skip the philosophical arguments about whether the try/catch should even be in the language. Why doesn't your code work?

You are trying to catch a catchable exception, @fullofsquirrels answer does not apply to your case.

I have tested your code on both OS X and iOS (simulator only), both throw and exception, and both allow you to catch it. In other words there is nothing wrong with your code *per se*, it is correct and should work...

So there is something else outside of the scope of the code you've posted which is causing the issue. You'll have to dig.

As a starting point you might look at the stack trace and see if that offers any clue as to the cause.

Happy hunting!